# JavaScript click event listener on multiple elements and get target 'rel' attribute

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Code:

```
var articles = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].addEventListener('click',redirect,false);
}
function redirect(){
    alert(this.rel);
}
```

This code works for attribute `id` but not for attribute `rel`. Can anyone help me to get `rel` attribute?

Comment: alert(this.id); returns the id of the particular li

Comment: `this.getAttribute('rel')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be accessing these attributes with `element.getAttribute('attribute_name')`

`alert(this.getAttribute('rel'));`

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that "these attributes" == attributes that are unsupported for that type of element. Attributes that belong there should become properties, except for a few corner cases like `class`. Attributes that don't belong there should probably become `data-` attributes if it's under the OP's control.

Comment: +1 A very good point, I was vague in my description of the attributes that have to be accessed this way. Personally, I access all attributes this way so that I'm not going back and forth.